# Include assets when building library using ng-packagr

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, ng-packagr

Could anyone give a hint where to start to include images and css files into Angular library using ng-packagr?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's an official issue for that question [here](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/123). It's actually quite simple *to include* images and the like to your library: You can just copy them to the dist folder manually after `ng-packagr` has done its thing.

However, it's more difficult to automate the extraction of those files in projects that'll use your library. In the issue referenced above BenjaminDobler suggests to add the following mapping to the `.angular-cli.json` file of any consumer project:

```
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/my-lib/assets", "output": "./assets/my-lib/" }
```

I feel this is more of an NPM issue, though, and there also are bare NPM solutions for it like [pkg-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg-assets) and [npm-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-assets).

Answer (score 33):

It's an old thread but still updating with a latest options in Feb-2020

With the ng-packagr ^9.0.1 version, You can do this using inbuilt "copy assets"

```
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "assets": [
      "CHANGELOG.md",
      "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
    ],
    "lib": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md

This has helped me remove the postpackage cp scripts

Adding my actual ng-package.json for benefit of others. I wanted to copy the assets folder and all its contents to the library and publish it along with it.

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/common",
  "assets": [
    "assets"
  ],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "common": "common"
    }
  }
}
```

The assets folder is in the library root directory. this helps to copy the entire assets folder and the contents inside it and add it to the library, so that you can use it as  @include "@node_modules/your-library/assets/styles/main.scss"

Comment: Please, a complete example

Comment: Added the sample of ng-package for copying the assets folder. unfortunately I dont have a complete library as an example.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm Angular v8.3.20 and on a projectType: library I got:
ERROR: Configuration doesn't match the required schema.
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties (assets).

Comment: @Akostha You need to define this in the ng-package.json of the library.

Comment: @Silvos I did it in the ng-package.json, but weirdly with the last version of angular, no files are copied... And still have then error at bundling.

Comment: @Silvos ok then.. I am trying to copy a wasm-glue.js file.. but assets are copied AFTER the bundling.. So I'm completely stuck because I don't find "hook" that allows me to copy wasm-glue.js before FESM2015 bundling happens.

Answer (score 9):

It can be automated on Linux with `post*` script

```
"scripts": {
    "package": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json",
    "postpackage": "cp -R YOUR_ASSETS_FOLDER dist/YOUR_ASSETS_FOLDER && tar -cvzf dist.tgz -C dist .",
    "release": "npm publish dist"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also got same problem when I packaging using ngPackagr. So I wrote my own small node script to copy them to the dist folder manually.

> npm install wrench

create new js file in the root **assets-copy.js**

```js
var wrench = require("wrench"),
  util = require("util");

var source = "./src/assets";
var target = "./dist/src/assets";

wrench.copyDirSyncRecursive(source, target, {
  forceDelete: true
});

console.log("Asset files successfully copied!");
```

add build script to **package.json** like below,I called it as **manual:assets-copy**

```js
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json",
    "assets-copy": "node assets-copy.js"
  }
```

After you run

> npm run packagr

Also run our script

> npm run manual:assets-copy

It'll copy them to the dist folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "postbuild". It works for me.

on **package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "ng build",
    "postbuild": "cp -R projects/mylib/src/assets dist/mylib/assets",
...
```

**IMPORTANT**... when to execute the build uses:

> **/> npm run build**

Then the "postbuild" will execute automatically. It will not execute if you uses only "ng build".

Comment: `'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`